# How do I take the input text from a html form and pass it to another form on the same page with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I'm new to JQuery and I'm trying to add a feature into my Rails application that takes an input from a html form and runs it through some erb on the same page.

Here is what I have so far in jquery and html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#search" ).on('submit', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var film = $( "form input:text" ).val();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="search">
    <form>
      Film:<br>
      <input type="text" name="film"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="results">
    <%= form_for @film do |f| %>
      <% @search = Tmdb::Search.new %>
      <% @search.resource('movie') %>
      <% @search.query("Film to be queried)"%>
      <% @results = @search.fetch %>
      <% @select_list = @results.collect {|movie| [ movie['title'] + " " + movie['release_date'][0..3],
         movie['title'] + "," + movie['release_date'][0..3] + "," + movie['id'].to_s + "," + movie["backdrop_path"].to_s ] } %>
      <%= select_tag "film_record", options_for_select(@select_list) %>
      <%= f.submit "Add film" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Where is says "Film to be queried", I want to put the film variable element set in my jquery.

I'm happy to do this a completely different way, so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Use ajax and rails helper method: remote: true  in your first form.  I'd write out a step by step guide but there are many videos and tutorials on the subject already so start there!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there is no need to set variable jquery inside form rails. You can get attributes by `params` in your form.

Notice that the search input has a name attribute called 'film', so you can access it when get back to the view, after submit form, using `params[:film]`, like this:

`<% @search.query(params[:film])%>`

I hope that help you.